# aws ElastiCache redis slowlog has command named COMMAND

Tags: performance, redis, command, amazon-elasticache

I have a rails service on aws, and I use elasticcache(redis).When i get redis slowlog,there are so many command like 'COMMAND'.

```
93) 1) (integer) 1176043
    2) (integer) 1525704863
    3) (integer) 1135
    4) 1) "COMMAND"
94) 1) (integer) 1176042
    2) (integer) 1525704862
    3) (integer) 1005
    4) 1) "COMMAND"
95) 1) (integer) 1176041
    2) (integer) 1525704807
    3) (integer) 1040
    4) 1) "COMMAND"
```

I never call command like 'COMMAND' in my code.I can't find any slowlog with 'COMMAND' in my local development enviroment.And i'm not sure what 'Command' means.
Any body can help me?